# How to remotely modify credentials for the WinRM service on multiple machines

Tags: windows, scripting

I am trying to prepare our environment consisting of Windows XP / 7, Windows 2003 / 2008 for PowerShell remoting. I have configured the WinRM service and listeners as well as a firewall inbound rule through Group Policy following Microsoft Procedures. However, I used the GP Editor on my admin station (RSAT) rather than the one on the DC and it offered one additional configuration option which should have never been configured. Namely the credentials under which the service would run. Untouched it automatically picked up my domain admin account.  Now the WinRM service is configured under the wrong account and it won't start up on any of the machines. Server or client. When I try to manually start the service on any machine, I get the following error message:

```
Windows could not start the Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) service on Local Computer.

Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process"
```

After some research and tinkering I learned that the service is supposed to run under the Network Service account with a blank password by default. When I manually change the credentials on any machine to Network Service and clear the password boxes, I get a confirmation popup:

```
The account NT AUTHORITY\Network Service has been granted the Log On As A Service right.
```

After that the WinRM service starts up just fine. I need to find a way to remotely change the credentials for this service on multiple machines. Obviously I cannot use PowerShell as the service is a prerequisite for PSRemoting. I did try `sc.exe` in a startup script through GPO on a test OU with one machine like so:

```
sc.exe config "WinRM" obj= "Network Service" password= ""
net stop WinRM
net start WinRM
```

Unfortunately however, it did absolutely nothing. I have UAC enabled on all win7/win2008 machines I also have WinXP and Win2003 boxes.

Does anyone out there have any idea for a solution? Maybe a  script that might work? I am not much of a cripting guy, so if you are kind enough to help me out with a script can you also tell me how to use it?

All responses will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this post.  the following command will work for accomplishing the above.

sc.exe config "WinRM" obj= "NetworkService"

In testing I found that the NetworkService account actually has no space between the two words, but in GUI it does show space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few months late, but hopefully this can help someone. I just resolved this issue in both my test and production environments by configuring the Group Policy preference for the WinRM service and manually entering:

```
User: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
Password: <space>
```

**Exactly**. You have to manually enter the account name as I wrote it, and the password is a single space. Other combinations of username and password have not worked for me.  If other combinations work, I'd love to know.